# Type or namespace name 'IUnzipper' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying to run a simple implementation of Virtual Buttons in Unity using Vuforia.
My current versions are : Unity 5.6.1

And I'm recieving *Type or namespace 'IUnzipper' could not be found (are you using a missing directive or assembly reference?)*

My C# Script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class vbScript : MonoBehaviour, IVirtualButtonEventHandler {

GameObject zombie;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    zombie = GameObject.Find ("zombie");
    GameObject virtualButtonObject = GameObject.Find ("actionButton");
    virtualButtonObject.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour> ().RegisterEventHandler (this);
}

public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb) { 

    Debug.Log("button Pressed");
    zombie.GetComponent<Animation> ().Play ();

}

public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb) { 
    zombie.GetComponent<Animation> ().Stop ();
}
}
```

Error trace:
    *\VirtualButton3\Assets\Vuforia\Editor\Scripts\Unzipper\SharpZipLibUnzipper.cs(38,38): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IUnzipper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (Assembly-CSharp-Editor)*

Comment: I found this with a google seach [IUnzipper Missing](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/iunzippercs-unzippercs-missing)

Answer (score 0):

Google is a great resource. 
It appears that the template dose not always come with it in the folder.

Here is the link to it [link](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/iunzippercs-unzippercs-missing)